# How do I convert a 7-byte number saved in HEX format to a decimal number if the largest supported data type is 32-bits long?

Tags: hex, keil, mifare, 8051, uid

I am trying to output a 7-byte Unique Identifier (UID) from a Mifare Classic card to a screen in decimal format.

I have already read and split the UID into a HEX array containing the high and low nibbles. Therefore I have an array with 14 elements. If I had a 64-bit data type available, I would normally loop through the elements in the array and multiply them by the corresponding value to get the UID in decimal format. I would then separate each digit of the UID into an array to be output to the screen.

The issue is that the largest supported data type available is 32-bits on the Keil C51 compiler for 8051 processor.

Can somebody point me in the right direction please?

Pseudo-code example with 2-byte UID:

```
UID = 0x1234,  UID_array = [0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04], Decimal_value = 0, Decimal_digit[5] = 0

Decimal_value += 0x1000 * 0x01
Decimal_value += 0x100 * 0x02
Decimal_value += 0x10 * 0x03
Decimal_value += 1 * 0x04

Decimal_value = 4369

Decimal_digit[0] = (uint8)((Decimal_value/10000) % 10)

Decimal_digit[1] = (uint8)((Decimal_value/1000) % 10)

Decimal_digit[2] = (uint8)((Decimal_value/100) % 10)

Decimal_digit[3] = (uint8)((Decimal_value/10) % 10)

Decimal_digit[4] = (uint8)(Decimal_value % 10)
```

Comment: So I'm afraid that you need to implement your own "big integer" module, or search for such one. -- Why do you need the UID in decimal?

Comment: I need the serial number to be decimal so that the user can compare the S/N written on the back of the RFID card and the S/N printed on a screen. Thank you for your suggestion, will search for a 'Big Integer' module and keep you updated.